# Why would reducing "max server memory" in SQL Server improve my application performance?

Tags: sql-server

I have an intermittent problem with one area of my application where it starts running slow. The application is ASP.Net+ with SQL Server. We discovered by chance that making *any change* to the "max server memory" in SQL server, up or down, will immediately stop the problem.

The problem area is quite dynamic, and being updated simultaneously by many threads, so my current best guess to explain this is some kind of deadlocking problem in the DB. Unfortunately it happens very rarely, only on a live system and when it does happen we have to fix it quickly. As there is not a lot of opportunity for 'digging' I want to narrow my search and this oddity seems like a clue.

I have googled this, and looked in "Books Online" so I know that "max server memory" is not a setting that requires a restart. What I can't find is any detailed description of what happens when RECONFIGURE is called 'under the hood'.

My hope is that somebody here knows, or can point me at a more detailed resource. Just to be clear, I'm not asking for general advice so please try to stay specific. Thanks :)

Update:

Calling `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` does not have any effect on the problem, while bumping the memory continues to fix the symptoms immediately.

Comment: Can you tell us something about your hardware? It sounds simply like sql server eating all memory, and asp.net loosing breathing space, potentially starting to swap (which is dead slow)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea but I think that's unlikely to be the cause. The actual site is running on a different machine and SQL server is by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have a performance problem and you should approach it by investigating the performance, not by [guessing](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/31/the-bizzaro-guide-to-sql-server-performance/). Follow a performance troubleshooting methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) to identify the bottleneck, then take appropriate actions depending on the *identified* issue.

As to your speculations about 'internal deadlocks' they are ... creative. A more realistic explanation would be that by messing with server settings you're tickling the [clock hands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/11/20/495093.aspx) which evict your [bad plan](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Hi, could you expand on 'tickling the clock hands'? Why would an increase in available memory cause an immediate eviction of a query plan?

Comment: Run `select ... from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`. Do any change to `max server memory`. Run again `select ... from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`. [Surprise!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Bmhjf0rKe8) QED

Comment: On a serious note: plans are costed during optimization considering many factors, *including available memory*. It makes perfect sense that if the `max server memory` is modified in any way, all plans to be invalidated and force recompile *under the new memory conditions*.

Comment: So in summary, the answer to my actual question is: "Modifying `max server memory` causes SQL server to invalidate cached plans"?